# Facebook login not responding in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook

im using the facebook sdk in a Asp.net MVC 3 application.
Everything works fine in IE 9, Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.
However if i try to login in a IE7-IE8 browser mode it is not responding.
I get no errors either in the console, it just does nothing.

I tried looking for a answer for this but without succes.

I have `xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">`
 in my html element at the top of my page.

The problem is i cant give more information since i dont get any errors in my console.

Answer (score -1):

ok, i found what was causing this.

FB.login was called inside:

`window.fbAsyncInit = function() { ....}`

by removing this the problem was solved.